# how to eliminate the shadow of a tikzpicture in beamer

Tags: beamer, animations

I made a tikzpicture and I wanted to make shaded shapes but when I get to the page that contains the figure I find the shadows of all forms already present so there is a solution for them to appear with the figure since I also have an animation in the same figure knowing that it is a presentation in beamer.

Thank you

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!30!white, draw=blue!50!white,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=10},visible on=<4->] (8,1.833) rectangle (14.5,5);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!15!white, draw=blue!30!white,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},visible on=<4->] (9.25,4.75) rectangle  node[text width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<4->] {\textbf{Modélisation}}(13.25,5.25);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white, draw=blue!40!white,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},visible on=<5->] (8.333,3.5) rectangle  node[text width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<5->] {\small Poids \& poussée d’Archimède\normalsize }(11.0833,4.5);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white, draw=blue!40!white,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},visible on=<6->] (11.4166,3.5) rectangle  node[text width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<6->] {\small Dynamique\normalsize }(14.1666,4.5);

\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white, draw=blue!40!white,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},visible on=<7->] (8.333,2.166) rectangle  node[text width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<7->] {\small Propulsion\normalsize }(11.0833,3.166);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white, draw=blue!40!white,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},visible on=<8->] (11.4166,2.166) rectangle  node[text width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<8->] {\footnotesize Forces \& moments aérodynamiques\normalsize }(14.1666,3.166);


\draw [dashed,rounded corners=2.5mm,ultra thick, -latex,draw=blue!30!white,out=90,in=90,looseness=5,visible on=<9->] (8,3.4166)--(4.25,3.4166)--(4.25,2.75);



\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!30!white, draw=blue!50!white,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=10},visible on=<10->] (1,-1.25) rectangle (7.5,2.5);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!15!white, draw=blue!30!white,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},visible on=<10->] (2.25,2.25) rectangle  node[text width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<10->] {\textbf{Commande}}(6.25,2.75);
\draw[draw=blue!50!white,line width=0.35mm,visible on=<10->] (4.25,2.25)--(4.25,-1.25);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!15!white, draw=blue!30!white,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},visible on=<11->] (1.625,1.75) rectangle  node[text width=2cm,align=center,visible on=<11->] {\textit{Linéaire}}(3.625,2.25);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!15!white, draw=blue!30!white,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},visible on=<12->] (4.875,1.75) rectangle  node[text width=2cm,align=center,visible on=<12->] {\textit{Non-linéaire}}(6.875,2.25);

\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white, draw=blue!40!white,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},visible on=<13->] (1.333,0.4166) rectangle  node[text width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<13->] {Linéarisation}(3.833,1.4166);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white, draw=blue!40!white,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},visible on=<14->] (1.333,-0.9166) rectangle  node[text width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<14->] {Contrôle}(3.833,0.0833);


\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white, draw=blue!40!white,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},visible on=<15->] (4.5833,0.4166) rectangle  node[text width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<15->] {Commandeg}(7.0833,1.4166);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white, draw=blue!40!white,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},visible on=<16->] (4.5833,-0.9166) rectangle  node[text width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<16->] {Commandeg robuste}(7.0833,0.0833);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I guess you need to add an example. Assuming that you use the `beamer-overlay-styles` library, you may have to adjust the `shadow opacity` to your needs.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: You should not post the code into an answer, rather you should append it to your question. (I'm also wondering if [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440061/121799) solves your question...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `beamer-overlay-styles` makes things invisible by setting their `opacity` to 0. However, (blur) shadows have a non-zero opacity, which overrides the opacity from the `invisible` trick. So you need to block out the shadows as long as the nodes or other things are invisible. To this end, I define a style `blur shadow on` that takes two arguments, the overlay specification and the blur steps.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{blur shadow on/.style args={<#1> with #2 steps}{alt={<#1>{blur
shadow={shadow blur steps=#2}}{}}}}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Shadow opacity} 
\centerline{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.92] 
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!30!white, draw=blue!50!white,
blur shadow on={<4-> with 10 steps},
visible on=<4->] (8,1.833) rectangle (14.5,5);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!15!white, draw=blue!30!white,
blur shadow on={<4-> with 5 steps},
visible on=<4->] (9.25,4.75) rectangle node[text
width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<4->,font=\bfseries] {Mod\'ulisation}(13.25,5.25);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white, draw=blue!40!white,
blur shadow on={<5-> with 5 steps},
visible on=<5->] (8.333,3.5) rectangle node[text
width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<5->,font=\small] {Poids \& pouss\'e
d'Archim\'ede}(11.0833,4.5); 
\filldraw[rounded
corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white, draw=blue!40!white,
blur shadow on={<6-> with 5 steps},
visible on=<6->] (11.4166,3.5) rectangle node[text
width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<6->,font=\small] {Dynamique}(14.1666,4.5);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white, draw=blue!40!white,
blur shadow on={<7-> with 5 steps},
visible on=<7->] (8.333,2.166) rectangle node[text
width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<7->,font=\small] {Propulsion}(11.0833,3.166); 
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white,
draw=blue!40!white,
blur shadow on={<8-> with 5 steps},
visible on=<8->]
(11.4166,2.166) rectangle node[text width=2.5cm,align=center,visible
on=<8->,font=\footnotesize]
{Forces \& moments a\'erodynamiques}(14.1666,3.166);
\draw [dashed,rounded corners=2.5mm,ultra thick,
-latex,draw=blue!30!white,out=90,in=90,looseness=5,visible on=<9->]
(8,3.4166)--(4.25,3.4166)--(4.25,2.75);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!30!white, draw=blue!50!white,
blur shadow on={<10-> with 10 steps},
visible on=<10->] (1,-1.25) rectangle (7.5,2.5);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!15!white, draw=blue!30!white,
blur shadow on={<10-> with 5 steps},
visible on=<10->] (2.25,2.25) rectangle node[text
width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<10->,font=\bfseries] {Commande}(6.25,2.75);
\draw[draw=blue!50!white,line width=0.35mm,visible on=<10->]
(4.25,2.25)--(4.25,-1.25); 
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!15!white,
draw=blue!30!white,
blur shadow on={<11-> with 5 steps},
visible on=<11->]
(1.625,1.75) rectangle node[text width=2cm,align=center,visible
on=<11->,font=\itshape]
{Lin\'aire}(3.625,2.25); 
\filldraw[rounded
corners=5pt,fill=blue!15!white, draw=blue!30!white,
blur shadow on={<12-> with 5 steps},
visible on=<12->] (4.875,1.75) rectangle node[text
width=2cm,align=center,visible on=<12->,font=\itshape] {Non-lin\'aire}(6.875,2.25);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white, draw=blue!40!white,
blur shadow on={<13-> with 5 steps},
visible on=<13->] (1.333,0.4166) rectangle
node[text width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<13->] {Lin\'arisation}(3.833,1.4166); 
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white,
draw=blue!40!white,
blur shadow on={<14-> with 5 steps},
visible on=<14->]
(1.333,-0.9166) rectangle node[text width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<14->]
{Contr\'ole}(3.833,0.0833);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white, draw=blue!40!white,
blur shadow on={<15-> with 5 steps},
visible on=<15->] (4.5833,0.4166) rectangle
node[text width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<15->] {Commandeg}(7.0833,1.4166);
\filldraw[rounded corners=5pt,fill=blue!10!white, draw=blue!40!white,
blur shadow on={<16-> with 5 steps},
visible on=<16->] (4.5833,-0.9166) rectangle
node[text width=2.5cm,align=center,visible on=<16->] {Commandeg
robuste}(7.0833,0.0833); 
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I do not have your document preamble, which is (probably) the picture is too wide, and that you had some strange characters, which I could not copy, and replaced by ad hoc characters.