# is there way to remove shadows items in beamer that contains an animation

Tags: beamer

is there way to remove shadows items in beamer that contains an animation. If I do an itemize with animation, the items appear shaded from the beginning of the slide.

Thank you

```
  \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Calcul}
\begin{itemize}
\addtolength{\itemindent}{0cm}
\item<2-> Vitesses 
\item<3-> Positions 
\item<4-> Accelerations 
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess you will have to do the same trick as in your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443904/how-to-eliminate-the-shadow-of-a-tikzpicture-in-beamer). Without a code/example it is hard to be more specific.

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). This is not the default behaviour, probably something your theme does. But if you don't tell us what you are doing it is hard to solve your problem.

Comment: yes you are right but I do not know how to post an example I understood that it should not be put following the question

Comment: @Elyes To add additional information to your question, you can click on the "edit" link at the bottom of the question.

Comment: No, you should always add an MWE. What went wrong in your previous question is that you added the code of your *question* in the *answer* field. Please just edit your question to also include the code.

Comment: Thank you for editing your questions! Unfortunately this is not a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting from `\documentclass` until `\end{document}`

Comment: We really need to see how you managed to add shadows in the first place in order to try to help you.

Comment: thik you    I managed to insert a code in my message here now there is an example

Comment: Thank you posting a compilable short document. It does not produce any shadows for me.

Comment: ah it's good thank you the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is not the default behaviour. You probably use some theme or other setting which change the behaviour.

Try to use `\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}` after whatever changes the it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item item
\item bla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your proposal but it does not work, the shadow still persists

Comment: @Elyes Then we really need a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: \begin{frame}
\frametitle{Calcul}
\begin{itemize}
\addtolength{\itemindent}{0cm}
\item<2-> Vitesses 
\item<3-> Positions 
\item<4-> Accelerations 
 \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

Comment: @Elyes Please use the "edit" link below your questions and a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)!