# Documentation of additional keys or commands when using TikZ or pgfplots in beamer presentations

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots

After going through [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440061/2288), I wondered if there is a documentation of the available keys that can be used as options when drawing using TikZ or pgfplots.

For example, the key `alt` in `\node[alt={<2>{...` I didn't find it documented in either manual of TikZ or beamer.

So, where can I find good documentation of all the additional available keys that can be used when drawing using TikZ or pgfplots?

Comment: These keys come from `\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}`, which is not a library that ships with Ti*k*Z. You can look up the definitions of the keys by saying `texdoc aobs`. The styles you mention were introduced in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat off-topic question: would you please refer me to somewhere I can learn how to export beamer or animated tikz files to gif? Thanks

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Another question if you don't mind: I can't run the animation of  [this presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435890/2288) on either Adobe or Foxit despite enabling javascript. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Almost everything I know about animations and exporting them is written in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/472050), which links to several posts, perhaps most importantly [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136919/194703), which has the magical line `convert -density <density> -delay <delay> -loop 0 -alpha remove multipage.pdf animated.gif` in it. The resulting animations can be uploaded to posts of this site. Please let me know if I should expand on anything.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Many thanks, that was helpful to convert to gif. I just have one thing to resolve: how can I present the animation inside the pdf file itself when viewing in fullscreen? May I know which pdf viewer you use?

Comment: In other words, the beamer version here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435890/2288 results in 22 pdf pages, so how can I display these pages in a single animating frame?

Comment: You need to view it in full screen mode with acroread (or another "qualified" viewer, most viewers do not work).